# Full screen screenshot shows two neighbouring screens in one workspace for just one monitor, one of them an empty desktop

Tags: linux-mint, workspaces, screenshot

Could it be that Linux thinks by default that there is a second monitor, even if none is attached? I might also have forgotten about having changed the settings myself long time ago.

When I'm pressing the <kbd>PrtScn</kbd> ("Print Screen") button, it's taking a screenshot of two screens that are in the workspace, one with my opened applications that I see on the monitor and one empty desktop. When I check the workspaces with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>Up</kbd>, I see that I am in just one workspace, the other three are empty.

Strangely, if I take a screenshot again now that I played around with a WLAN connected TV and switched workspaces / virtual desktops with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>Right/Left</kbd> randomly, and after adding more applications, having many applications opened, I get only the one screen that I am looking at in that screenshot - this seems to work now. I do not know how to get back the error in question, but I know that I had it for many months so that I could not use the built-in screenshot app at all but had to change to flameshot.

One could say that this is fixed without knowing why, but I leave this question opened so far until it gets closed by votes. There might be other users with the same problem.

I have Linux Mint 20.04, but I think that this is a question for any Linux OS.

Comment: Are you taking about virtual desktops?

Comment: @user68186 no, I think it is about things only inside the workspace, inside the virtual desktop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can "sort of reproduce" it after having added an HDMI cable as the connection to a projector:

[image]

This should be what this is all about, I had another monitor connected and forgot about it, or I had an issue with my HDMI driver.

Since I now have a second monitor (the projector), <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>Up</kbd> rightly shows two windows:

[image]

And with <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>Windows</kbd><kbd>Left/Right</kbd>, I can bring the windows from the right side to the left projector side and back:

[image]

This must have been the problem over the months, and then on top, I must have forgotten when I had a second monitor plugged in and not. Meaning: this Q/A is likely a mere stupidity. I will either rewrite this and ask how I can take a screenshot of only one of the two monitors or leave it to be close-voted. For now, or until I take the time for this, I will not delete it since someone else might be as stupid.